# NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery

Tags: jpa, nosuchmethoderror

I need to call a stored function `StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = manager.createStoredProcedureQuery("fncpreparaordemorcamento");
storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("tax", Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
storedProcedure.execute();
Integer tax = (Integer)storedProcedure.getOutputParameterValue("tax");`

I got this error **NoSuchMethodError:javax.persistence.EntityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery**

Here my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>rh</artifactId>
    <groupId>br.com.etout</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>rh-web</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>rh - web</name>

<url>http://jboss.org/jbossas</url>
<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
    </license>
</licenses>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Import the JAX-RS API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
        in JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
        JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
        JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in
        JBoss AS 7 -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>uaihebert.com</groupId>
        <artifactId>uaiCriteria</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.5-beta3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dependency on the EJB module so we can use it's services if needed -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.etout</groupId>
        <artifactId>rh-ejb</artifactId>
        <type>ejb</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
    <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
    <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-el-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Java EE 6 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: So you have a JPA API jar in the CLASSPATH that is before v2.1 (yes I know you have a v2.1 as well, but you also have a v2.0 or 1.0 there) hence the message. Fix your CLASSPATH

Comment: As Neil Stockton writes: you have a scope:provided dependency on JPA 2.1 API, but I really believe that JBoss 7 is JPA 2.0 API, that does not contain this method. So you either: (1) upgrade the application server, (2) stop using this method or (3) stop relying on the provided JPA implementation and include the desired with the application.